# Nativescript css calc()

Tags: css, sass, nativescript

i used css calc() function but it gives error. But n the nativescript documentation says that nativescript can support calc().
[here example of using calc()](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui-and-styling.html#css-overview)

My code:

```
.card {
    --my-variable: 5;
    width: calc(50% - var(--my-variable));
    width: calc(50% - 5);
}
```

It is error which i get:

Error: Failed to apply property [width] with value [calc(50% - 5)] to GridLayout(550). Error: Invalid value: calc(50% - 5)

Any comments, links can help me

Comment: Hello, 5 what ? px, % ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus, no. In nativescript it means maybe dp or something like this

Comment: Though quite late: If you read the docs you can clearly see that - and + are not allowed, only multiplication